# providedIn Property In Angular Service Is not working

Tags: angular, angular-services, injectable

I am learning Angular DI, But The Provided Example (https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules) Is Not Working Can Anyone Help me In Understanding Here Is The Link Of The Stackblitz I Am Working On.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k1gvth
Thanks,
Keshav

Comment: Stackblitz link is missing, also please specify the part which is not working.

Comment: Can you expand more on what "not working" means?

Comment: Please explain what issues you're having in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AppService to your providers array in app.module.ts as specified in the docs.

Comment: But I want to achieve it using only providedIn strategy. If I inject service in module then I even don't need to write @Injectable() in service.

Comment: You need to use Injectable annotation any ways to be compatible with Angular DI. If you just want to providedIn without adding it to providers you need to use it as providedIn: 'root' as mentioned by @Shabbir Dhangot

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use provideIn value as `root`. With that no need to provide in app module.

```
 providedIn: 'root'
```

If you want to add this in `app.module.ts` then remove Injectable decorator from service and add in providers list of app.module.ts.

You can read official documentation for more details. https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Also You can't give module name in providedin. There are predefined options for that 'root', 'any' and 'platform'. You can read more at https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable

Comment: But I want to achieve it using only providedIn strategy. If I inject service in module then I even don't need to write @Injectable() in service.

Comment: @KeshavSharma Read my updated answer that will clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add providers in the `app.component.ts` file. I have added the snippet below and it working fine.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { AppServiceService } from './app-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [AppServiceService]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor(ser: AppServiceService) {
      this.name = ser.sayHello();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is also one of the way document suggested. But I want to achieve it only using providedIn property of @Injectable. BTW Thanks for commenting. :)